# JSON returned with the word "POST" at the beginning

Tags: php, jquery, html, json, ajax

I swear I am going crazy. Using the stack template from envato market and everytime I try to do a simple ajax request the json return from php is invalid. I am using the identical code in another template and it works fine.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "../api/login",
    dataType: 'json',
    type: "post",
    data:{
        login:login,
        pass:pass
    },
    success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            token = data.token;

    },
    error: function(data){
            console.log(data);

    }
});
```

This call cannot be more basic. I should be getting an array with a token in it instead I get

```
POST"8b025621d238f1bf715941067a33dc1f"
```

Its the POST thats throwing me. It doesn't happen in any of my other applications. The php code that makes the return is here

```
function checkLogin(){
    include "logindb.php";
    $password = $_POST['pass'];
    $login    = $_POST['login'];

    $db       = new adminLogin();
    $result   = $db->logInUser($login);
    $id       = $result['id'];
    $hash     = substr( $result['hash'], 0, 60 );
    error_log("hash is-->>$hash");
    if(password_verify($password, $hash)){
      $status = "login successful";
      $token  = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
      $token  = bin2hex($token);
      $result = $db->addToken($id,$token);
      error_log("login successful");
    }else{
      error_log("login failed");
      $status = "Unauthorized";
      header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized', true, 401);
    }
    $returnValue = json_encode(array('response'=>$status,'token'=>$token));
    echo $returnValue;

}
```

Any insight is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: There's someting earlier in your PHP script that's echoing `POST`. Impossible to tell from why that's happening from the little snippet you posted.

Comment: Try echoing `$token`

Comment: Why do you think you should be getting an array? You didn't do `echo json_encode(array('token' => $token));`.

Comment: @Barmar is right.. Post more

Comment: There's no way that output could be coming from that function. Ignoring the `POST` prefix problem, should look like `{"response": "login successful", "token": "8b025621d238f1bf715941067a33dc1f"}`.

Comment: *"I am using the identical code in another template and it works fine."* - Does that other template also use a custom method? If not, then it's a variable scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in your current edited PHP code, there are no flaws.

It seems that you already echoed `POST` before calling `checkLogin()`.

Try to check your code once and remove that `echo` part. You will be good to go.

Comment: @sixstring Something is echoing `POST` *before* you call `checkLogin()`.

Comment: solved the problem. Barmer was correct. I was chasing jquery so much I missed it.